# how to fix add function of my dynamic input?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mongodb, tailwind-css, prisma

I have a modal that will ask user to register their dorm, in my modal i have rules that the user can add rules. but when i click add and input text when i add another input field it has the same value with the first one. and another problem when i click next the input fields are missing.
this is my code for dynapicinput component

```
'use client';

import { 
  FieldErrors, 
  FieldValues, 
  UseFormRegister 
} from "react-hook-form";
import { BiDollar, BiSolidTrash } from "react-icons/bi";
import { IoMdCloseCircleOutline } from "react-icons/io";
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface AddDynamicInputProps{
    id: string;
    label: string;
    type?: string;
    disabled?: boolean;
    formatPrice?: boolean;
    required?: boolean;
    register: UseFormRegister<FieldValues>,
    errors: FieldErrors
}


const AddDynamicInput: React.FC<AddDynamicInputProps> = ({
    id,
    label,
    type = "text", 
    disabled, 
    formatPrice,
    register,
    required,
    errors,

}) => {
   const [val, setVal] = useState<string[]>([]);
   
   const handleAdd = () => {
       const abc = [...val, ""];
       setVal(abc);
   }
   
   const handleChange = (onChangeValue: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>, i: number) => {
       const inputdata = [...val];
       inputdata[i] = onChangeValue.target.value;
       setVal(inputdata);
   }
   
   const handleDelete = (i: number) => {
       const deletVal = [...val];
       deletVal.splice(i, 1);
       setVal(deletVal);  
   }

   console.log(val, "data-");
   
   return (
     <>
       <button onClick={handleAdd} className=" bg-orange-400 rounded-full p-4 shadow">Add</button>
       {val.map((data, i) => {
           return (
               <div key={i}>
                <div className="
                        w-full 
                        relative 
                        flex
                        flex-row
                        items-center
                        justify-center
                        gap-5
                        pb-5
                     ">
                    {formatPrice && (
                        <BiDollar
                        size={24}  
                        className="
                            text-neutral-700
                            absolute
                            top-5
                            left-2
                        "
                        />
                    )}
                    <input
                        id={id}
                        disabled={disabled}
                        {...register(id, { required })}
                        placeholder=" "
                        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
                        type={type}
                        className={`
                        peer
                        w-full
                        pt-6
                        p-4
                        font-light 
                        bg-white 
                        border-2
                        rounded-md
                        outline-none
                        transition
                        disabled:opacity-70
                        disabled:cursor-not-allowed
                        ${formatPrice ? 'pl-9' : 'pl-4'}
                        ${errors[id] ? 'border-rose-500' : 'border-neutral-300'}
                        ${errors[id] ? 'focus:border-rose-500' : 'focus:border-black'}
                        `}
                    />
                    <label 
                        className={`
                        absolute 
                        text-md
                        duration-150 
                        transform 
                        -translate-y-3 
                        top-5 
                        z-10 
                        origin-[0] 
                        ${formatPrice ? 'left-9' : 'left-4'}
                        peer-placeholder-shown:scale-100 
                        peer-placeholder-shown:translate-y-0 
                        peer-focus:scale-75
                        peer-focus:-translate-y-4
                        ${errors[id] ? 'text-rose-500' : 'text-zinc-400'}
                        `}
                    >
                        {label}
                    </label> 
                    <button onClick={() => handleDelete(i)}>
                        <BiSolidTrash
                            size={24}
                            color="orange"
                        />
                    </button>
                    </div>
                  
                   <hr />
               </div>
               
           );
       })}
     </>
   );
}

export default AddDynamicInput;
```

this is my code for RentalModal

```
if (step === STEPS.POLICIES) {
    bodyContent = (
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-8">
        <Heading
          title="Rules"
          subtitle="What is the rules of your dorm"
        />
        <AddDynamicInput
          id="policies"
          label="Rules"
          disabled={isLoading}
          register={register}
          errors={errors}
          required
        />
        
   
      </div>
    
    )
  }
```

to add input fields that are not the same as the first one and if i click next the input fields and values will not be gone